# Shiny deployment error

Tags: shiny

When I am trying to deploy my shiny app at shinyapps.io I get below error :

```
> deployApp()
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 187055...DONE
Deploying bundle: 857060 for application: 187055 ...
Waiting for task: 416072120
  building: Processing bundle: 857060
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 849457
  building: Installing system dependencies
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2017-06-07T17:28:40.200495546+0000] Execute script: packages/build/nloptr.sh
+ set -e
+ VERSION=2.4.2
+ cd /tmp
+ curl -O http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 416072122 failed: Error building image: Build exited with non-zero status: 56
```

Has anyone come across this error. Appreciate if someone help me on how to resolve this. I am using R version 3.4.0

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app require `NLopt`, but shinyapps.io failed to install the package. The package installation seemed to be some shell script which may not work in the shinyapps.io server(because of permission etc).

[Basically the deployment process scan your file and environment](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud), then try to duplicate the dependency packages in the server. If you used CRAN version the server will also install CRAN version, which should not need build from source or running some shell script. If you used github version server will also try to use github version or build from source, which could have more dependency requirement.

Another possibility is the R package is just the interface and you need to install the actual library, which failed to be installed in server.

> R packages will often rely on operating system packages to be
>   installed on the server. If your application happens to use an R
>   package that requires a system library that is not installed by
>   default, please let us know by filing an issue, or a pull request, at
>   [shinyapps-package-dependencies](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies)